# Masking Corona Tableview for all devices

Tags: lua, tableview, coronasdk, mask

I am creating a tableview using corona.  This is working fine, and is displaying in the right coordinates using a maskfile, at least for one device.  If i view the tableview on another device, the result is different because the size of the maskfile is fixed (320x480).  Viewing the app on other device, android devices specifically bigger ones, there is an empty space and it looks messy.

The only solution I find is to create mask for all possible screen sizes, perform a size check then fetch the correct mask file.  I am prepared to create all these mask png files, but am just curious whether anyone knows a more efficient way of accomplishing this without increasing the size of the app.

here's my code for `tableView`

```
local tableView = widget.newTableView
{
    top = 100,
    width = 320, 
    height = 366,
    maskFile = "assets/mask-320x420.png",
    listener = tableViewListener,
    onRowRender = onRowRender,
    onRowTouch = onRowTouch,
}
group:insert(tableView)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to do it.  Tableview only supports custom scroll bars and background colors.  It might be easier just to make your own tableview by just making a for loop and inserting all of the values into a table.  If you make your own tableview, you can add masks and customize it way more.

Hope this helps.